# iPython in Terminal.app: multi-line editing

Tags: mac, python, terminal.app, ipython

I'm using iPython in Terminal.app (on Mac), and when I scrollback to a multi-line block it's really slow moving between lines. Is there a keybinding (or can I configure one) to make it possible to easily move between lines quickly?

Answer (score 1):

Ipython depends upon the readline bindings. In looking through the [man page for readline](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline+3), I could not find a command that skips by lines, but moving by words is better than moving by character, so I have added the lines

```
c.TerminalIPythonApp.exec_lines = ['import readline',
  """readline.parse_and_bind('"5D" backward-word')""",
  """readline.parse_and_bind('"5C" forward-word')"""]
```

to my `ipython_config.py` file (for details on this file see [the ipython start up files reference](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/overview.html#startup-files).)  Note that the `"5D"` comes from what appears on my screen when I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>left</kbd>, and similar for <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>right</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick check and with the latest version of iPython I don't have the same problem.

Have you installed the gnu readline package or the python equivalent? If you haven't then I'd recommend "sudo pip install readline" at the terminal prompt.