# Where are ipython key bindings documented?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ipython

I'm mostly loving ipython, but exasperated by my efforts to find any documentation for keyboard shortcuts. I can arrow/scroll through my command history, I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> to search my history, a la bash, but other bash/readline commands <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to delete a word or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> to delete a line don't work. I've seen plenty of questions that seem to be about keyboard shortcuts and key bindings, but not a lot of answers.

[iPython in Terminal.app: multi-line editing](https://superuser.com/questions/489642/ipython-in-terminal-app-multi-line-editing)

I'd settle for unindent help right now -- ipython does a nice job of indenting for you when you start a loop or function definition, but it seems like I must be missing something everytime I <kbd>backspace</kbd>  <kbd>backspace</kbd>  <kbd>backspace</kbd>  <kbd>backspace</kbd> to unindent when I'm done with my loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPython is built on [GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) - the same basis for command line editing in bash.

Readline's user [documentation](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) covers keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to <kbd>backspace</kbd>, just push <kbd>enter</kbd> again when you want to end your block; the blank line will signal the end of the block and the extra space will be ignored.

```
In [17]: for i in range(2):
   ....:     for k in range(1):
   ....:         print i,k
   ....:         
   0 0
   1 0

In [18]:
```

Comment: Awesome. That's even easier than ctrl-a, ctrl-k